# Why is the word "parent" not pronounced as suggested?

Tags: pronouns, transcription

The word "parent" has this transcription: `ˈpeərənt` (I took it from [longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/parent)). Here the letter "A" is in 4th form (when `vowel + R + vowel`). So it should be read like in words "care" and "bare". It has correct transcription, but when I listen its pronunciation, I hear a short sound `e` like in word "get".

Why is it pronounced in the different way as its transcription?

Comment: The standard pronunciation is the same as in "care" or "bear". The vowel may be shortened in rapid speech but it should retain some of its quality.  I think this is your perception, rather than an incorrect transcription.

Comment: Looks to me like Longman shows both pronunciations. Did you listen to both?

Comment: @JamesK Oh. I clearly hear two vowel sounds after sound `k` in the word "care". But I head the only one sound between `p` and `r` in the word "parent". :(

Comment: @DanGetz Yes, there are two transcriptions and two pronunciations in longman: British and American. I hear the singlу sound in both of them (they are slightly different, but it definitely the single sound). And how I see the American transcription `ˈperənt` is correct. It contains the only one sound. But the British variant confuses me.

Comment: @HaruAtari  *I clearly hear two vowel sounds after sound k in the word "care".* - do you mean like "kay-er"?  Because it should really be one syllable, but some accents stretch it out.

Comment: @stangdon Not exactly. I mean the sound `e` transferring into `ə`. Technically it's a single sound but contains two parts. In the `parent` I hear only `e` part of it.

Comment: I don't hear what you hear, I hear the same sound as in care and bare.

Comment: Questions that start "Why is..." are not well suited to the site. There is a vast amount of grammar, vocabulary, syntax and pronunciation that is irregular in English - and studies of why this is the case is not really what we do. I agree with you about "parent" - one would logically expect it to be pronounced the way it is in French - but it isn't. There undoubtedly is a reason, but one that will be lost in the mists of time. And I fear it is unlikely that you will discover it here.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't take too seriously guidelines on pronunciation, unless they are clearly for a specific geographical region or cultural scope. Words are pronounced the way they are pronounced and the notion of "should" doesn't really have much force.

For example, I am a native English speaker, but from Scotland. I would not pronounce "parent" in either of the two ways given in that web page. Instead, I and many of my fellow countryfolk would say something like pay-rint. And we would ignore anyone who dared suggest that our pronunciation was not what it should be.

---

Note: That said, we would also pronounce the single syllable word, "film" as "fill-um", and the two-syllable "magnet" as "mah-gih-nit". So ah'd be careful takin' prih-nunce-iation advice fae the likes o' us!